# How can i change the color if the value is 25? Because the value "<= 50" is taking over with the yellow color of the "25" value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My "Health <= 50" is changing color if it's under 50. But when i hit 25 i wanna change it to red. (Im in Unity, C#) As tagged. I've tried many compbs and researched but aint found any answers. Thanks for reading!

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SomethingFunction : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Text Informationsystem;
    public int Health 100;

    void Start()
    {
        TxtUI= GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Test();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        if(health <= 50)
        {
            TxtUI.color = Color.yellow;
        }
        else if(health <= 25)
        {
            TxtUI.color = Color.red;
        }
        else if(health >= 50)
        {
            TxtUI.color = Color.white;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: What would happen if you swapped the order of the conditions? Ex: `if (health <= 25) { } else if (health <= 50) { }` Also, your final condition should probably be `health > 50` to remove the overlap it currently has with the `health <= 50` condition.

Comment: You should check first the most restrictive condition when using `if-else if`. In your case you should start it like: `if (health <= 25) { red} else if (health <= 50) {yellow} else {white}`

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly! :D I just swapped the color & values as you said. Also the little  
">" in the end. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Please research how if-else statements work.

The problem here is that if, for example, the health is 19:
Then the color will be set to yellow, because 19<50.

Because of the else if statement the other checks are not executed. You can either change the order of if-else statements or remove the else part:

```
if (health <= 25)
        {
            TxtUI.color = Color.red;
        }
        else if (health <= 50)
        {
            TxtUI.color = Color.yellow;
        }
        else if (health > 50)
        {
            TxtUI.color = Color.white;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, either change the if-else order (like you did) or use `>25 && <= 50` to catch the actual range.